# Conflicting return type in implementation of 'supportedInterfaceOrientations': - Warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

After upgrading to Xcode 7.0 I get a warning in the UIViewControllerRotation method: `- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations`:

> Conflicting return type in implementation of
>   'supportedInterfaceOrientations': 'UIInterfaceOrientationMask' (aka
>   'enum UIInterfaceOrientationMask') vs 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned
>   int')

Why is that, and how do I fix it?

**EDIT:**
If you go to the definition you'll see that the return type acctually has changed:
`- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);` but changing the return type in the code doesn't silence the warning.

Comment: NEVER silence a warning (unless you are an expert who has answered himself why it is a good idea). Fix the code.

Comment: @gnasher729 OP obviously meant “quell” or “satisfy“ the warning, not silencing it outright.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Try this tweak:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED < 90000  
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations  
#else  
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations  
#endif  
{
   return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Comment: Only do this if the code base needs to be compiled using both Xcode 6 and 7. If you are fully switching to Xcode 7 then simply use `- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations`.

Comment: @rmaddy is it related to XCODE version or to IOS version?

Comment: @nurne Both really. The iOS version determines the API availability but the Xcode version defines the Base SDK being used.

Comment: @rmaddy can you elaborate further?

Comment: @QED What is defined, such as `UIInterfaceOrientationMask` and `__IPHONE_9_0` is based on Xcode version, but iOS version determines whether something is available, such as dark mode, hence the need for `#available`. I know it's been 3.5 years, so if you can explain it better than me now, feel free!

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying here

Answer (score 10):

I am using this one:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED < __IPHONE_9_0
#define supportedInterfaceOrientationsReturnType NSUInteger
#else
#define supportedInterfaceOrientationsReturnType UIInterfaceOrientationMask
#endif

- (supportedInterfaceOrientationsReturnType)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

... a little bit longer than Nishant's fix but a little bit clearer, I think.

Comment: The `__IPHONE_9_0` isn't defined in pre-iOS-9 Xcodes (technically, iOS SDK installs under `Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs`) so this won't compile unless you're using Xcode 7.  @Nishant's solution of using an int literal is the solution to this.  If not that, you could check `__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED > __IPHONE_8_4`, but that's far more fragile and still requires an iOS 8.4 SDK install (Xcode 6.4; won't work in Xcode 6.3.2).

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson Okay. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: That said, you could still make this work but you'd have to define `__IPHONE_9_0` yourself.  I.E. In your PCH, do: `#ifndef __IPHONE_9_0` _[newline]_ `#define __IPHONE_9_0 90000` _[newline]_ `#endif`

Answer (score -1):

I have been at this for a few weekends to figure out the proper solution, I have tried many others solutions but just did not work properly. If you want only certain UI to be in landscape or Portrait try this method below. I am running Xcode 7.2.1 , I am using a Bool to set the value along with NSUSerDefaults in each Class I want to follow specific UIInterfaceOrientations.The method below gets called each time there is a new UI presented or when the device is rotated , you could check this by putting a NSLog checking the value of the bool in that method and see for yourself how it changes.

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:
```

In you AppDelegate do  the following

.h @property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL shouldRotate;

.m

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(nullable UIWindow *)window  NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0) __TVOS_PROHIBITED{


_shouldRotate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"rotateKey"];
NSLog(@"Did I get to InterfaceOrientation \n And the Bool is %d",_shouldRotate);

if (self.shouldRotate == YES)
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
        else
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
```

}

NOW IN EVERY CLASS YOU WANT TO HAVE A SPECIFIC UIINTERFACEORIENTATION DO THIS

```
 -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [super viewDidAppear:YES];

   // [[AppDelegate sharedAppDel]setShouldRotate:YES];
    BOOL rotate = NO;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:rotate forKey:@"rotateKey"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];

}
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
```

In the Views you want to rotate change the Bool value to Yes. 
Now in your AppDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    BOOL rotate = NO;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:rotate forKey:@"rotateKey"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];


    return YES;
}
```

Also in your AppDelegate

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.

    BOOL rotate = NO;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:rotate forKey:@"rotateKey"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize]; 
}
```

Hope this helps many developers.
Tested and Tested many times.

Regards

JZ

Comment: ur answer is bit confusing. My whole project is in portrait mode and i want only single view in tab bar controller to be auto rotation. how it could be done.